# Taking numbers from a const array and adding +2 to each number | Must Use for Loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
    const addTwo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    
    for (let i = addTwo.length; i >= 5; i++) { 
      addTwo = addTwo += 2 //I know this does not work
  
      
    }
    
  console.log(addTwo); // -> should print [3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
```

Hi there,

New to js and working on using an array with a for loop. In this problem it's asking me to specifically use a for loop to get a solution. I was able to get my answer using splice. But, to be honest I thought this was a little heavy handed and lazy to me. I didn't think it was going to help me learn anything. I have exhausted many options online. Looking at various videos on the subject of for loops.

I just felt I could use some help from the pros. I get a "Type Error on line 4: Assignment to constant variable." Now, as I understand you can't change a constant variable. Any ideas what I could use as a beginner? Thank you for your patience and help!

Comment: Try `for (let i = 0; i < addTwo.length; i++) {
  addTwo[i] += 2;
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign to the array element, not the whole array. And the indexes in the loop are wrong. You should start from 0 and go up to the length-1. Your loop will repeat infinitely because `i >= 5` is always true when you start with `i = 5` and keep adding 1 to it.

```js
const addTwo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for (let i = 0; i < addTwo.length; i++) {
  addTwo[i] += 2;
}

console.log(addTwo);
```

Comment: Thank you! So, why would I write addTwo[i] += 2 instead of addTwo += 2? i represents the index of the array? 1,2,3,4,5?  Thank you again!

Comment: You can't add to an array, you can only add to numbers. `addTwo[i]` is the element of the array at index `i`.